# AutoHotKey - Why does it not work in the game

Tags: autohotkey

The game is Grim Dawn and run with Steam, the script is simple, as follows

```
$1::
    Send {1}
    sleep 100
    Send {3}
Return
```

I use the administrator to run this script, but it has no effect in the game, may i ask what is the cause?

Comment: [This](https://forums.crateentertainment.com/t/ahk-script-not-working/46210) might be hepful

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Use ctrl+alt+5 is work, but use any single key to mapping is not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried it, only using $ as the hotkey mapping method did not work, so I changed a method, as follows

```
#ifWinActive ahk_class Grim Dawn
loop{
    if GetKeyState("RButton")
    {
        sleep 300
        if GetKeyState("RButton"){
            Send {1}
            sleep 100
            Send {2}
            sleep 100
            Send {3}
            sleep 100
            Send {4}
        }
        
    }
    sleep 50
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ctrl+alt+5 trick works, then this would be the updated script that should automate those keys when you click your custom hotkey:

```
$1::
    Send !^5
    Sleep 3
    Send !^5
    Send {1}
    sleep 100
    Send {3}
Return
```

Comment: I mean hotkey is not work, like this, use !^5:: as the hotkey is work，use $1:: is not work,

Comment: Finally, I use RButton:: instead of other hotkeys, it's worked now, thanks for your comment.